# PHP: parsing data from Cube XML format

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I can't find a solution on the official docs, so here is my scenario:

I need to parse data out of this xml: http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml

This is the code i've implemented until now:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml');
foreach($xml->Cube->Cube as $x) {
    $arr[date('d-m',strtotime($x['time']))] = array();
    foreach($xml->Cube->Cube->Cube as $y) {
        $arr[(string)$y['currency']] = (float)$y['rate'];
    };
};
```

Problem is that this code will obviously parse only the first set of rates while i need to parse each rates set for each date, then i need to change `$xml->Cube->Cube->Cube` with something else that i don't know how to declare! Might be only a sintax question then...

**UPDATE**

I'm almost there:

```
foreach($xml->Cube->Cube as $x) {
    for ($i=0;$i<90;$i++) {
        foreach($xml->Cube->Cube[$i]->Cube as $y) {
                $arr[date('d-m',strtotime($x['time']))][(string)$y['currency']] = (float)$y['rate'];
        }
    }
}
```

Problem here is on line #3: the `foreach` won't accept the variable `$i` and it returns `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. If i use a single index istead of the variable (for example `0` or `1`) it will work. So now the problem is how to increment the index dynamically! :(

Comment: what about using a xslt query?

Comment: @philipp i've never used this method, could you please make a practical example? I've read here [(w3schools.com)](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp), but it's not really clear to me how to apply it to this case

Comment: `//Cube/Cube/Cube` or `//Cube[@currency and @rate]` returns a list of all `<Cube>` Elements you desire… To run the query on simple xml, you should have a look here: http://php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: @philipp don't think it's what i need. I almost find a solution, i update the question.

Comment: Well, i think this `//Cube[@currency and @rate]` xpath query will return a list/array containing all `<Cube>` elements, having a currency and a rate attribute, explicitly. You can iterate over that list and you are done. This will work even if the structure of the xml changes, as long as it contains `<Cube>` elements with those attributes. Your loop approach will work too, but instead of writing three nested loops, you can end up with a single one. The decision is up to you, but I think the xpath approach is more robust and readable.

Comment: @philipp you are probably right, but i can't figure out how to apply the sintax of your method to this case...

Comment: @philipp this `$xml->xpath('//Cube[@currency and @rate]')` is returning an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there was a little trick using the namespaces, but that's the code:

```
<?php
    $xml  = simplexml_load_file('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('d', 'http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref');
    $list = $xml->xpath('//d:Cube[@currency and @rate]');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>xpath</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <table>
           <tr>
               <th>id</th>
               <th>currency</th>
               <th>rate</th>
           </tr>

           <?php $count = 0; ?>
           <?php foreach ($list as $cube): ?>
           <?php $attrs = $cube->attributes(); ?>
           <tr>
               <td><?php echo ++$count; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $attrs['currency']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $attrs['rate']; ?></td>
           </tr>
           <?php endforeach; ?>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```